# C++ spec: can duplicate methods share same pointer/address?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Just asking about C++ spec/standard,
and this has nothing to do with Qt, but some Qt knowledge is appretiated;

Does the C++ spec/standard allow two methods to have same pointer, I mean, in case compiler's optimization detects that the methods are binary-same, is compiler allowed to emit binary once for both?

### Example:

```
class MyClassA {
     inline void maybeOptimize1() {
         // Some code.
     }
};

class MyClassB : public MyClassA {
     inline void maybeOptimize2() {
         // Imagine exact same code as `maybeOptimize1()` here.
     }
};

static_assert(&MyClassB::maybeOptimize2 != &MyClassA::maybeOptimize1);
```

### Importance:

For example, in Qt framework we have `QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod`, which if passed to `static_metacall(...)`, can be used to find index of method/slot based on method's pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of an address for non-static member functions in the C++ standard. There is no possibility of obtaining the address (in the sense of an instruction/symbol address in the compiled code) of such a function.

However, pointer-to-member do exist and `static_assert(&MyClassB::maybeOptimize2 != &MyClassA::maybeOptimize1);` is guaranteed to succeed if both functions are non-virtual and inheritance relation is given. (Otherwise the result of the comparison is unspecified which in the manifestly constant evaluated context of the `static_assert` would imply that the program would be ill-formed.) See [[expr.eq]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.eq#4).

How this is implemented is up to the compiler. For example in the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-function-pointers) for non-virtual non-static member functions, a function pointer is stored together with an object pointer adjustment and I don't think deduplicating the functions would generally allow to differentiate the pointers given that the base class object offset is zero, so it wouldn't be a permitted optimization. (At least assuming the class has external linkage. Otherwise I could see the compiler reasoning statically about which addresses are being taken.) Maybe it would be possible if the offset is non-zero, so that the object pointer adjustment differs. I would need to think about this in more detail.

As far as I know MSVC's implementation of member pointers is not standard-conforming, so I can't tell how it will behave there.

However, compilers are clever enough to e.g. reduce one of the functions with the same body to just a jump into the other in order to save on duplicating instructions. This still provides unique symbol addresses for the emitted functions.

I can't say anything about `QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod`, whether it relies on member pointers, uses compiler-specific non-standard methods instead, or whether it relies on hacks that are technically UB and therefore outside the spec (which isn't uncommon).

Comment: Thanks; Qt compares pointer-to-member (where we pass one such pointer-to-member as input to the helper, and Qt uses its auto-generated C++ source-code, which compares our input to each method/slot's pointer-to-member).